# import numpy - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing mtrand

Tags: python, windows, numpy, pip

I need your help to solve this issue.
I've tried many of the published answers, and none has worked for me yet.
Here's what I'm trying to do:

`(testnumpy) c:\Users\wonka\test\testnumpy>python -c "import numpy"`

This is the message it got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Users\wonka\test\testnumpy\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 156, in <module>
    from . import random
  File "c:\Users\wonka\test\testnumpy\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\__init__.py", line 179, in <module>
    from . import _pickle
  File "c:\Users\wonka\test\testnumpy\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_pickle.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .mtrand import RandomState
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing mtrand: No se encontró el proceso especificado.
```

I've tried inside and outside virtual environments, directly in python, from console with python -c, and many more different things.
I'm currently working under Windows 10, with these versions:

`C:\Users\wonka>python --version Python 3.9.0a5`

`C:\Users\wonka>pip --version pip 21.0.1 from c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)`

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Install numpy from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo! For both the edit and the link.
I tried them, numpy-1.19.5+vanilla-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl was the only one that worked for my PC, but I still get similar errors like the first one, this time it ends in `Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: No se encontró el proceso especificado`.

Comment: I just couldn't figure out what happened 
I decided to downgrade Python to 3.8.1 and NumPy to 1.17.3 and it worked just fine. I guess I'll create a virtual environment for it in the meantime.

Comment: I was using poetry and pyenv and downgrading from 3.9.0a5 to 3.8.2 worked for me, kept numpy at 1.20.1! Thank you!

Comment: same error for me (Win10 64b, Py 3.9.0a4, numpy 1.20.1) in a pyenv / venv environment.